# Trouble with null reference on stage properties in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flash-cs5

I am making a website in Flash, coded in flashbuilder. Whenever I try to export my code I get the same error again and again (TypeError = see below).

I think the problem has something to do with the stage of my project. Whenever I change the `var stageMiddenX = (stage.stageWidth / 2);` into `var stageMiddenX = 512;`, the code works. but I wan't the var to be dynamic.

> TypeError
>   Error #1009: cannot access a property or method of a null object reference at main()

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;

  public class main extends MovieClip{
    var stageMiddenX = (stage.stageWidth / 2);
    var stageMiddenY = (stage.stageHeight / 2);
    private var object1:Object1 = new Object1();
    private var object2:Object2 = new Object2();
    private var object3:Object3 = new Object3();
  }
}
```

Comment: W4cko, I fixed your question, but *please for the love of all that is holy*, learn how to format correctly on Stack Overflow. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @Michael Petrotta : Thx for the help with the format :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that `stage` is not yet available at the time you are requesting it.

You'll want to wait until the `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` event is fired before attempting to acccess `stage`.

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class main extends MovieClip{
        private var object1:Object1 = new Object1();
        private var object2:Object2 = new Object2();
        private var object3:Object3 = new Object3();
        private var stageMiddenX:Number;
        private var stageMiddenY:Number;

        public function main(){
            if(stage) init(null);
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init)
        }

        private function init(e:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            stageMiddenX = (stage.stageWidth / 2);
            stageMiddenY = (stage.stageHeight / 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This process isn't required if the class above is the document class.. Which I'm not sure if the example is.. So +1 anyway!

Comment: I thought I'd recalled having issues with trying to access `stage` "too early" (even in the document class). However, I just did a quick check and found that you are correct. I would vote up your answer if I had enough rep.

Comment: Marcela is right on this one. Document classes are no exception.

Comment: @Jackson Have you actually tried accessing stage from within the constructor of a doc class? Works fine.

Comment: In my previous flash project I used my original AS code and it worked. In this project I had difficulties with the exact same code :s strange don't you think .. BUT the problem is solved thanks to you guys. THX !!

Answer (score 1):

Put the stuff accessing stage into a constructor (assuming this is your document class)..

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class main extends MovieClip
    {
        public var stageMiddenX:int;
        public var stageMiddenY:int;

        private var object1:Object1 = new Object1();
        private var object2:Object2 = new Object2();
        private var object3:Object3 = new Object3();

        public function main()
        {
            stageMiddenX = stage.stageWidth / 2;
            stageMiddenY = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        }
    }
}
```